# Are dragon fights buggy in the current version of Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've experienced odd behavior in 3 different dragon fights.  At first the dragon would just stay in the sky and not move as I hit him.  When the dragon has about half its life remaining, it starts move very strangely (jerking in every direction, flying backwards, etc..).

Then when I kill it, it is still flying around and the game start to lag like crazy.  Is anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, after the latest patch many people have reported weird dragon behavior. [For example dragons flying backwards.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YaNZHfdCF_0)  This should be resolved in a later patch.

Comment: well this is exactly what I am experiencing, hopefully it will be fixed soon

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in Patch 1.3, which is currently live for PC users via Steam, and should be availiable for PS3 and 360 this week (Week of December 12, 2012.)

Comment: yea, they are working again