# How can I kill an erratic dragon?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are dragon fights buggy in the current version of Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39856/are-dragon-fights-buggy-in-the-current-version-of-skyrim)

I have run across a dragon that is erratic in behavior. He just flops around the sky like a fish on dry land. I can hurt it with magic, but the more health I drain from it the slower frame rate I get. (I am on the xbox version).

This is problematic for two reason.

1. After flopping around he teleports, making it hard to kill him.
2. He will often teleport into my area making it impossible to fast travel.

Since the dragon *doesn't* attack me, number two isn't a big problem except that I am getting around 5-6 FPS making walking mind-numblingly slow.

What can I do here? I can't seem to kill it, and it shows up randomly. (The first time I saw it was at the location of the Frost Breath #2 shout. Ever since them it has been plaguing me.)

[Here is a quick video of it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNIO7zqxDzM&feature=youtu.be). You can kind of see how slow the framerate is by the fireball I am casting.

Comment: Are you on the PC?

Comment: as mentioned I am on the xbox :)

Comment: Wow I have never seen that before. Are you able to get him to a town or somewhere that the NPC's can kill it? Have you killed it yet even though the frame rate is really bad? Im hoping that once your able to kill it the corpse will fall.... Hopefully lol.

Comment: Are you running the latest patch (1.3)? I believe this exact behavior was fixed.

Comment: I was last prompted for an update a week ago, so I assume I am on the latest patch.

Comment: @Nappa82 Yes, he has come to town, but the NPCs ignore it. I tried killing it, but it is difficult at 5ish FPS. I'll keep trying though

Comment: Same thing happens on PS3.

Comment: Now that I look more closely, it appears that Patch 1.3, which fixes the issue, while live for PC via Steam, isn't scheduled to hit XBox or PS3 for another few days. So, sometime this week, it'll be fixed.