# Dragons are buggy - how to resolve?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are dragon fights buggy in the current version of Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39856/are-dragon-fights-buggy-in-the-current-version-of-skyrim)

I have a problem with my dragons in Skyrim on the xBox 360.
Whenever I encounter a dragon, it behaves buggy.

It never attacks me but flies to a distant spot and stays still in mid-air.
I can go into fire range and cast on the dragon until its health goes down to a certain level (about one third of its max health). Then it flies away again, sometimes itt flies backwards, out of range. When I follow the dragon and come into fire range again it is at full health.

This happens at every encounter with a dragon in the open field (except for the first 'wild' encounter from which I finally ran away after being killed several times).
When this lasts a bit longer, the gameplay starts feeling laggy and it becomes really slow after some minutes, frames are bing skipped.

So I can't kill any dragons and each encounter is really annoying.

What can I do so that dragon encounters work again like they are supposed to be?

Comment: What version of Skyrim?

Comment: 'The latest'. Like the last update from a week ago or sth. like that. Whenever my Xbox offers me an update, I'll download and install it.

Comment: This has been fixed in Patch 1.3, which should be hitting for the 360 sometime this week.

Answer (score 0):

What difficulty level are you using? I've found that if you have it on the easiest setting, dragons are incredibly unwilling to engage in combat with you - they just turn up, fly around and attack things nearby, but rarely come close enough to allow you to do them any damage (or vice versa). Raising the difficulty up a few levels makes them more prone to attacking.

Comment: If he had to run away from his first encounter after being killed several times, he's almost certainly not on the easiest setting.